# gets() function is not available in Visual studio 2015 community

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have faced a compiler error(c3861) in my newly installed Visual studio community 2015 IDE:

I just want to use **gets()**  function from stdio.h library, and i have included `stdio.h` file in my program, but compiler show me a compiler error
like below:

```
error C3861: 'gets': identifier not found
```

What should i do to compile my program correctly with`gets()` function.

Comment: Maibe this is a Windows Runtime app? see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2029ea5f.aspx

Comment: @Gusman, Is there any way to disable CRT features. Actually I need `gets()` function for competitive programming.

Comment: But is it a WinRT app or not?

Comment: @Gusman, How do i know is it WinRT app or not. I have no idea about WinRT.

Comment: Ok, then it should not be a WinRT app, WIndows RT apps are for the WIndows store. Is your app a console app? post some code so we can see what happens

Comment: Yes this is absolutely console based program and this program is for online judge system

Comment: and my compiler also does not allow me to use `printf()` function unless I'm use  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: @maruf  `printf` is replaced by `printf_s` for the same reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you are looking forward to `learn` about

> buffer overflow vulnerability

you simply can use it and anther unsafe functions by the fallowing steps

1. from the solution explorer right click on the project and choose properties
2. navigate to  Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> Advanced
3. change `Compile As` value to `Compile as C Code (/TC)`
4. (optional) if you would like to disable the warning just put its warning number in `disable specific warning`

Answer (score 27):

Since C11, `gets` is replaced by `gets_s`. The gets() function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflows. The recommended replacements are `gets_s()` or `fgets()`

```
gets_s(buf);
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `gets` function was considered too dangerous (because it can *easily* cause a buffer overflow), so it was removed from the latest revisions of both C and C++.

You are supposed to use `fgets` instead. With that function you can limit input to the size of your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`gets` and`_getws` are removed from the beginning of vs 2015 because these functions are obsolete.
Alternative functions are `gets_s` and `_getws_s`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes gets() is not available now. The following worked for me:

```
 int main() {
    char file_name[30];
    cout << "Enter file name:";
    gets_s(file_name);
    cout << endl << "Selected file : "<< file_name;
    return 0;
}
```